# How to decrypt a hard drive with LUKS encryption?

Tags: ubuntu, luks, disk-encryption

today i was installing ubuntu on an external hard drive and in the initial setup i marked the option "encrypt installation" and the clicked the install button, but i didn't notice that my internal hard drive(which has windows 10 into it) was selected.

When i clicked install a pop up showed up saying that 3 partitions were going to be deleted, so at that moment i noticed i choose the wrong drive, i cancelled the installation, went back, choose the right drive and i continued with the installation (This time i left the encrypt option disabled).

So far, so good with ubuntu, but when i failed to boot from windows i realized that i encrypted the whole drive!

I need the files back, i have no idea what to do next! Please help, i read i needed to do a back up, but i dont even know how to access the drive.
Any comments or suggestion will we welcome.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried something similar to this from for example a live OS or rescue boot menu from a linux installation media (cd dvd usb etc...)

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sd<yourEncryptedDiskId> <aNameThatwillBeCreatedIn:Dev/mapper>
```

Like for exemple :

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda tmpData
```

and then

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/<TheNameUsedEarlier> /mnt #wherever you want
```

so as in the exemple :

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/tmpData  /mnt #wherever you want
```

now you can access your data.

Now that what needed to be done is done you can close the device :

```
$ sudo umount /mnt  
$ sudo cryptsetup luksClose  tmpData
```

Comment: Hello, @M4rty after entering the pass phrase i get "Cannot use device /dev/sda3 which is in use (already mapped or mounted)." Any Ideas?

Comment: when you type $ sudo mount , is sda3 listed?

Comment: I restarted Ubuntu, and it let me see the device in which is created: sda              8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1           8:1    0   512M  0 part  
├─sda2           8:2    0   488M  0 part  
└─sda3           8:3    0 930,5G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt 252:0    0 930,5G  0 crypt                                                    Now i don't know what to do, if i try to mount it i get "mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'"

Comment: @PauChittaro Do you have LVM installed? `sudo apt install lvm2`